# JavaFX UI freezes on web service call

Tags: javafx, jersey, fxml

I have a JavaFX application that consumes web services via Jersey Client API, every once in a while parts of the application(screens) freeze while executing a call to a web service.

There is no thread that i used to make the web service calls.

The following is the Jersey Client Code:

```
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.DefaultClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.json.JSONConfiguration;
    public class WSClient{
        WebResource webResource;
        ClientResponse response;

        protected Client getWSClient() {

            ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();

            clientConfig.getFeatures().put(
                    JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, Boolean.TRUE);

            Client wsClient = Client.create(clientConfig);
            return wsClient;
        }

        public ArrayList<String> getNames(){
            ArrayList<String> names= new ArrayList<>();

            try{
                webResource = getWSClient().resource("http://localhost:8080/names");
                response = webResource.type("application/json").accept("application/json").get(ClientResponse.class);

            }catch(Exception ex){
                log.error("Failed : " + ex.getMessage());
                return null;
            }
            if(response.getStatus() != 200){
                return null;
            }
            String output = response.getEntity(String.class);
            names= getGson().fromJson(output,
                    new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {
                    }.getType());



            return names;
        }
    }
```

The Following is the JavaFX controller class:

```
private ComboBox<String> cmbNames = new ComboBox<>();

cmbNames.setItems(FXCollections.observableList(new WSClient().getNames()));
```

your help is really appreciated!

Comment: Of course it freezes, it you do the work in the GUI thread.

Comment: does that mean that i have to write a thread that executes each and every web service call?

Comment: You can use`javafx.concurrent.Task`. You really shouldn't write your own threads, use what JavaFX provides for you.

Comment: the very reason i asked this question is because i have tested the web services via a browser client i.e Postman, Advanced REST Client...

and it turns out that the lag only happens when the call is from JavaFX. Of course for long processing tasks i have used the Task utility, and it only happens every once in a while

Comment: Well, those are most likely working asynchronously too.

Answer (score 4):

Retrieving data from a server is, or at least has the potential to be, a long-running operation. You should not perform such operations on the FX Application Thread, as the UI will be unresponsive during the operation.

Create a `Task` to perform the operation, and execute it in a background thread:

```
Task<List<String>> getNamesTask = new Task<List<String>>() {
    @Override
    public List<String> call() {
        return new WSClient().getNames();
    }
};

getNamesTask.setOnSucceeded(e -> 
    cmbNames.getItems().setAll(getNamesTask.getValue()));
```

To execute the task in a background thread, you can either do so "by hand":

```
Thread thread = new Thread(getNamesTask);
thread.setDaemon(true);
thread.start();
```

Or (better), use an `Executor` which will manage a thread pool for you:

```
// declared at class level:
private final Executor exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(runnable -> {
    Thread t = new Thread(runnable);
    t.setDaemon(true);
    return t ; 
});

// ...

exec.execute(getNamesTask);
```

For more strategies on integrating client-server communication with JavaFX, have a look at [Adam Bien's excellent article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javafxinteg-2062777.html).

Comment: Interesting that you defined the `onSucceeded`  as a lambda, but the task as an inner class , why not have that as a lambda, too?

Comment: You can't, because `Task` is not an interface. (It would be nice if `Task` defined a convenient factory method taking a `Callable`, something like `public static Task<V> ofCallable(Callable<V> callable)`, which would enable `Task<Something> t = Task.ofCallable(() -> ...);`.)

Comment: you should actually be able to, because task has just a single abstract method and thusly obeys the `@FunctionalInterface` contract. have you tried?

Comment: Nevertheless, a class is not a functional interface, even though it has the same pattern. There was some discussion about allowing classes with one abstract method to be targets of lambda expressions, but the final [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.8) did not include that definition (I don't remember why).

Comment: See [here](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2013-March/008441.html) for relevant discussion.